# Fragment URL in Openid - what does it mean?

Tags: http, url, openid, yahoo, identity

If I use my Yahoo-Account as an Openid-Provider it returns this url as my identity:

```
https://me.yahoo.com/a/9dodtB5.udVP6zRSRfAxIzPO6XXVdbqlS4jp#85bb1
```

What I think is odd is the fragment after the hash tag `#`.

Those fragments by HTTP standard don't get transferred to the server when requesting a resource. The only way I am aware of accessing them is within the clients browser using JavaScript.

So how can it be part of an Openid Identity or can it not?

So if I enable my website to accept Openid I get an Identity that I store in a Database and that I query for exact matches if a user wants to log in / register.

Should I store the fragment or not?

I think it doesn't hurt because all Openid-Libraries that I have seen so far store the identity AS-IS (with the fragment).

But isn't it some sort of Violation or the standard? I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of an addition to the Standard in Openid 2.0 that says the following:

> IDENTIFIER RECYCLING
>
> OpenID identifiers can be recycled over time, and OpenID 2.0 specifies
>   that OpenID Providers append URL fragments to the end of an OpenID URL
>   as a generation identifier. The entire OpenID URL with the fragment,
>   if present, should be used to identify the user. For instance, the
>   following two OpenIDs are unique and represent different users:
>   http://openid.example.com/username#aa
>   http://openid.example.com/username#bb

So it in the end really makes sense, because the identity itself doesn't really change. Meaning if I request the openid, the fragment gets stripped, and I always request the same resource with the same XRDS document behind.